How to add an arrayList field in a class file using ASM
I am doing changes to re-develop Jacoco.
Except for the existing boolean[], I want to add a new field (ArrayList) to store function name.
I have already create the init method and add it to 'addMember' like following
public Test() {
        boolean[] var2 = $jacocoInit();
        ArrayList var3 = $jacocoListInit();
        super();
        var2[0] = true;
        var3.add("<init>");
        Long a = 1L;
        var2[1] = true;
        var3.add("<init>");
        Long b = 2L;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        var2[2] = true;
        var3.add("<init>");
    }

But when i run the test
    @Test
    public void testInstrumentClass() throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = instrumenter.instrument(
                TargetLoader.getClassDataAsBytes(InstrumenterTest.class),
                "Test");
        TargetLoader loader = new TargetLoader();
        Class<?> clazz = loader.add(InstrumenterTest.class, bytes);
        assertEquals("org.jacoco.core.instr.InstrumenterTest", clazz.getName());
    }

It will throw java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "Ljava/util/List;" in class file org/jacoco/core/instr/InstrumenterTest
What's the root cause and how to solve it?
The codes i made changes are as follows.
public void addMembers(final ClassVisitor cv, final int probeCount) {
        createBooleanDataField(cv);
        createArrayListDataField(cv);
        createBooleanArrayInitMethod(cv, probeCount);
        createArrayListInitMethod(cv);
    }

private void createArrayListDataField(final ClassVisitor cv) {
        // declare an arrayList
        cv.visitField(InstrSupport.DATAFIELD_ACC,
                InstrSupport.METHOD_FIELD_NAME, InstrSupport.METHOD_FIELD_DESC,
                "Ljava/util/ArrayList<Ljava/lang/String;>;", null);
    }

private void createArrayListInitMethod(ClassVisitor cv) {
        // declare jacocoInit method
        final MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(InstrSupport.INITMETHOD_ACC,
                InstrSupport.INIT_ARRAYLIST_METHOD_NAME,
                InstrSupport.INIT_ARRAYLIST_METHOD_DESC,
                null, null);
        // edit the content of the method
        mv.visitCode();
        mv.visitTypeInsn(Opcodes.NEW, "java/util/ArrayList");
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, "java/util/ArrayList",
                "<init>", "()V", false);
        if (withFrames) {
            mv.visitFrame(Opcodes.F_NEW, 0, FRAME_LOCALS_EMPTY, 1,
                    STRING_FRAME_STACK_ARRZ);
        }
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ARETURN);

        mv.visitMaxs(2, 0); // Maximum local stack size is 3,
        mv.visitEnd();
    }

@Override
    public void insertProbe(final int id) {

        // For a probe we set the corresponding position in the boolean[] array
        // to true.

        mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, variable);

        // Stack[0]: [Z

        InstrSupport.push(mv, id);

        // Stack[1]: I
        // Stack[0]: [Z

        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_1);

        // Stack[2]: I
        // Stack[1]: I
        // Stack[0]: [Z

        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.BASTORE);

        mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, variable + 1);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEINTERFACE, "java/util/List", "add",
                "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z", true);
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.POP);

    }```


public static final String INIT_ARRAYLIST_METHOD_NAME = "$jacocoListInit";
public static final String METHOD_FIELD_DESC = "Ljava/util/List;";
public static final String INIT_ARRAYLIST_METHOD_DESC = "()Ljava/util/ArrayList;";


Your code is incomplete. What’s striking, is the contradiction between creating fields but expecting the values in local variables (in the pseudo code at the beginning, there are no fields at all). Further, there is no need to place a stack frame before a return instruction (that is not a branch target). The ClassFormatError suggests that you are using the signature string ("Ljava/util/List;" or METHOD_FIELD_DESC) at a place where a class name is expected. But, as said, your code is incomplete.

By the way, providing the generic signature ArrayList<String> for a field whose a raw type is List, is contradicting, but on the other hand, there is no point in providing generic signatures for this kind of Instrumentation anyway. The injected members are never going to provide an API for human programmers.
